# Convert String into Key-Value Pair in Java

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I know I there is a way to split using delimeter but the string I have is similar to JSON.

This is the string

```
[{type=Callback, output=[{name=prompt, value=InputCode}], input=[{name=IDT1, value=}]}, {type=TextOutputCallback, output=[{name=message, value={"current_type":"Code","info":{"some_key":"cf2fc86a","some_type":"Code","ph_no":"111111111"},"attempt":2}}]}]
```

Now I want to convert it in a way I can extract "attempt". So, I want to do something like this

```
String attempt = map.get("attempt");
```

The problem is that this isn't a valid JSON cause most of values aren't in double quotes.
What would be the best way to extract that?

Comment: It is not quite clear: do you need to extract specifically `"attempt"` key without parsing JSON?  Or you need to convert the given string into some POJO, where value can be a `Map<String, Object>` containing nested maps?

Comment: I need to specifically extract "attempt" from above string

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `String` structure doesn't change and `attempt` is the last field, you can work with the `String` without converting it to some POJO or `Map`:

```
public static String getAttempt(String json) {
    return json.split("\"attempt\":")[1].replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", "");
}
```

Then you can do:

```
SString json = "[{type=Callback, output=[{name=prompt, value=InputCode}], input=[{name=IDT1, value=}]}, {type=TextOutputCallback, output=[{name=message, value={\"current_type\":\"Code\",\"info\":{\"some_key\":\"cf2fc86a\",\"some_type\":\"Code\",\"ph_no\":\"111111111\"},\"attempt\":2}}]}]";

String attempt = getAttempt(json);

System.out.pritnln(attempt);
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

The map from the given input using a regular expression to match and parse some values.

Assuming that valid keys are written as alphanumeric identifiers with optional underscore inside double quotes, and the values can be placed inside double quotes or as integer numbers, the following pattern may be implemented and used to build the map:

```java
Pattern keyValue = Pattern.compile("(\"\\w+\")\\s*:\\s*(\"[^\"]+\"|\\d+(.\\d+)?)");
Map<String, String> map = keyValue.matcher(raw)
    .results()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        kv -> kv.group(1).replace("\"", ""), // strip off double quotes
        kv -> kv.group(2).replace("\"", ""), // strip off double quotes
        (v1, v2) -> v1 // or join if needed String.join(";", v1, v2)
    ));

map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
System.out.println("\n====\nattempt=" + map.get("attempt"));
```

Output:

```
ph_no -> 111111111
some_key -> cf2fc86a
some_type -> Code
attempt -> 2
current_type -> Code

====
attempt=2
```